# Using/redirecting multiple domain names with single dns zone

Tags: domain-name-system, azure, amazon-route53

I have one master domain name for one of my web sites. I also have many other domain names as secondary. All my DNS records are on my master domain name and for other domain names I just create zones and www records to redirect web requests to master domain name.

I plan to move my DNS service on Microsoft Azure DNS or Amazon Route 53. Since they are charging me for each DNS zone I would like to keep the DNS zone number to a minimum for cost effeciency.

Therefore, I want to create only two zones to use one and keep my master domain name and its records; use a second one to keep all the other domain names and redirect all the requests to master zone.

Is that possible? How can I do this? If I can't what is the best alternative?

Answer (score 0):

No, DNS doesn't work that way.

A hosted zone will only host records at, or under, its apex.  The `example.com` zone can only host records for `example.com` and it's subdomains.  It can't host record for any other domains.

After the first 25 hosted zones, Route 53 only charges you $0.10/month for each additional hosted zone.  If that seems to anyone like a cost that is excessive, that strikes me as unreasonable... particularly when the most obvious alternative is to host the domains on your own servers, which will cost more to host than hundreds of domains at that price, and still more in time and administration hassle.

Of course, some DNS registrars throw in DNS hosting and domain redirection to the "real" web site for free.  If all you are doing is redirecting requests to a main site, that's another straightforward solution... though the cost of maintaining your registration with other registrars in the interest of getting that "Free" service may be higher than registration + DNS hosting + web redirection.

Incidentally, redirecting web requests to another server is not done in DNS configuration alone.  That also requires a web server to accept the request and tell the browser to rewrite its address bar and navigate to the destination site.

Inside AWS, you can accomplish that redirection using Route 53 hosted zones, and empty S3 buckets configured for redirects.  If many domains are going to forward to the same destination, you can combine a single CloudFront distribution and a single empty bucket configured for redirection, and redirect 50 domains with and without www (100 unique hostnames) to one final server.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I think i am going to use our domain registrar dns server to just point out same web server with my master web site. It seemed best way to do it so i can manage it on my web server.

About he Route 53 billing. Each zone is $0.5 so for example for 30 zone it is $13